# Why if else statement dont work in project?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

Its always say dead. What is problem?

```
boolean death = false;
health = 100;

if (health < 0) {
    death = true;

    System.out.println("You are dead not a big suprise.");
} else {
    death = false;
}

if (death = false) {

    System.out.println("Living man.");
} else {

    System.out.println("Completely dead.");
}
```

Comment: `death=false` is an assignment not a comparison. It will assign death to false, and always be `false`. You want `!death` or `death==false`

Comment: A good IDE will inform you of that.

Comment: Since its an assignment, it will be always true. Thus you will see it always print out Living man.

Comment: @OngMingSoon the value of an assignment is the value assigned. So in that case `false`

Answer (score 0):

if you want use !=,you can write !death or death==false

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean death = false;
            int health = 100;

            if (health < 0) {
                death = true;

                System.out.println("You are dead not a big suprise.");
            } else {
                death = false;
            }

            if (!death) {

                System.out.println("Living man.");
            } else {

                System.out.println("Completely dead.");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

condition for checking eqaulity of death with false is wrong

```
if (death = false) {
```

this way, you are assigning false value to death.

*change it to* **==**,  as we use == for conditions.

```
if (death ==  false) {
```

**or**

```
if (!death) {
```